# How can I read a file and do template substitution?

Tags: substitute

## Question

How can I read a file into the current buffer and do some template substitution on it automatically?

## Background

I'm working on a simple bash-driven logging / journaling capability. [(on github, fyi)](https://github.com/jodavaho/bashlog)

I have a file that contains a templated todo item called `daily.tmpl` as follows:

```
- [ ] Check this weeks todo: 2020-$WW.md
```

I would like to be able to read that into my daily todo, and substitute `$WW` with the week.

I can capture the week number using `date +%W`. Or in vim: `:let weeknumber=date +%W` (with appropriate escaping omitted for clarity).

I can read the templated file to the top using `:read daily.tmpl`

So, I have created a bash alias that can open a daily todo item with a file name by date as:

```
alias todo=vim -c 'read daily.tmpl' `date`
```

## Option 1

What command can I execute to substitute, after read, `$WW` for the local vim variable `weeknumber`.

## Option 2

Is there another, better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `let weeknumber=date +%W` won't work at all. You want something like `let weeknumber=strftime("%W")`.

Second, the command for the substitution would be

```
:/$WW/substitute//\=weeknumber/
```

But simpler is

```
:/$WW/substitute//\=strftime("%W")/
```

> Is there  a better way

You could put the vimscript into a file (e.g., `todo.vim`) and run `vim -S todo.vim filename...`. Taking this further, you could use a here-document if your shell supports it:

```
vim filename -S <(cat <<DOG
/$WW/substitute//\=strftime("%W")/
DOG
)
```

See `:help -S`, `:help :substitute`, `:help range`, and `:help s/\=`

Comment: Instead of `system()` it's even better to use `strftime('%W')`. Also "a dollar sign" need not be escaped, as it is followed by a letter anyway (see `:h /$`)

Comment: Ah, very clean. I knew it would be coming from the right source.